Should newlyweds sleep under the same roof during the Sheva Brachot period?
When is the most appropriate time for newlyweds to start sleeping under the same roof together?

Under same roof right away. Except maybe case where she was nidda, then maybe would need some pple in same room to avoid yichud

Can’t see any reason at all to downvote the question. @T.R. Is the thinking behind your question based on the fact that after first intercourse the couple observe niddah separation? There is no problem with the couple sharing a bedroom subject to observing niddah separation.

I've edited the question title because of the ambiguous phrasing that was attracting downvotes (as it sounded like it was a question about relations, rather than yichud)

Why think a married couple shouldn't stay in the same house that you need to ask this?

If the Kallah is Niddah at the time of the wedding, then they should not stay in a situation of Yichud until she has been to the Mikva at the correct time.
If not, then they may (and should) stay under the same roof immediately.
See this Yo'atzot page for further information and suggestions. The couple of course should consult with a Local Orthodox Rabbi or a yoetzet.
